# How do I create a custom button using PySimpleGUI that will allow me to browse for files?

Tags: python, user-interface, button, pysimplegui

I'm currently trying to create a custom button in python using PySimpleGUI that allows me to browse for files. I am able to do this successfully for a button that submits my entries and one that cancels the process, but am unable to figure out how to do so without having to use `sg.FilesBrowse()`, which doesn't allow me to customize the button.

I have the current code for my window.

```
#select theme for GUI
sg.theme('Light Blue 2')

#create custom buttons
submit_button = sg.Button('', image_data=submit_base64,button_color=(sg.theme_background_color(),sg.theme_background_color()),border_width=0, key='Sumbit')

cancel_button = sg.Button('', image_data=cancel_base64,button_color=(sg.theme_background_color(),sg.theme_background_color()),border_width=0, key='Cancel')

#create GUI layout
layout = [[sg.Text('Please select the following files:', font = ('bold', 14))],
          [sg.Text('Page Names', size=(15, 1)), sg.Input(),sg.FileBrowse()],
          [sg.Text('Files to Replicate', size=(15, 1)), sg.Input(), sg.FilesBrowse()],
          [submit_button, cancel_button]]
```

In place of `sg.FileBrowse()` and `sg.FilesBrowse()` I would like to have my custom buttons similarly to how I created `submit_button` and `cancel_button`. I tried to follow the same format but am unsure what key I would have to use to have the button behave just like `sg.FileBrowse()` and `sg.FilesBrowse()`.

Thanks.

Comment: Make a button and call popup_get_file with no_window set to True in your event loop when someone presses the button.  Then fill in the input field.

Answer (score 1):

Try this.

Create a button
When button pressed call popup_get_file
Take results from popup and fill in the Input element

```py
import PySimpleGUI as sg

def main():
    layout = [  [sg.Text('My Window')],
                [sg.Input(key='-IN-'), sg.Button('MyBrowse', key='-BROWSE-')],
                [sg.Button('Go'), sg.Button('Exit')]  ]

    window = sg.Window('Window Title', layout)

    while True:             # Event Loop
        event, values = window.read()
        print(event, values)
        if event == sg.WIN_CLOSED or event == 'Exit':
            break
        if event == '-BROWSE-':
            file = sg.popup_get_file('', no_window=True)
            window['-IN-'].update(file)
    window.close()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```